# Weird blending behavior on PowerVR SGX544MP2

Tags: opengl-es, alpha-blending

On PowerVR SGX544MP2, sometimes blending behaves in a very strange way for me.

Instead of blending with the actual color from the previous draw calls, it tries to blend with black:

[image: The issue]
(sorry about the low quality, it's not my tablet and not my photo)

Some polygons render correctly, however (that blue hit decal on the left (which is blended with black in the middle, however), the beam and the HUD), but certain decals are broken.

How do I fix or work around the problem? It seems to be related to deferred rendering of tiles, but I don't really know. On other GPUs, it looks alright.

Comment: Seems to happen only when the framebuffer doesn't have an alpha channel. Weird since other GPUs treat no alpha as 1, not 0.